# Why Ingress needs an NodePort service?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I was reading the book "kubernetes in action", where it is mentioned that "Ingress controllers on cloud providers (in GKE, for example) require the Ingress to point to a NodePort service".

As Ingress controller fetch Pod IP from service itself and route the request directly to the IP and port, why does it need a `NodePort` service? and what does Node's IP and port (provided by NodePort service) used for?

Comment: Doesn't Ingress also work with load balancer IP service? I have seen in one project which I worked where ingress service was pointing to LoadBalancer service. But this was in AKS

Answer (score 0):

An ingress controller is typically used to route traffic from outside a cluster to services inside the cluster.A NodePort is an open port on every node of your cluster. Kubernetes transparently routes incoming traffic on the NodePort to your service, even if your application is running on a different node.

A NodePort exposes the application on a port across each of your nodes via ingress .NodePort Service in ingress is to enable external users to access the internal pods without entering the cluster.

Follow this [doc](https://blog.getambassador.io/kubernetes-ingress-nodeport-load-balancers-and-ingress-controllers-6e29f1c44f2d) for more information.

Comment: but it did not answer the actual question

Comment: please refer to [this](https://platform9.com/blog/understanding-kubernetes-loadbalancer-vs-nodeport-vs-ingress/) link

Answer (score 0):

An Ingress controller with NodePort will work the same way as a POD/Deployment exposed with NodePort Service. Ingress Controllers usually handle all the requests from the user and based on the rules route them to different pod services inside the cluster.
Without an Ingress Controller, you had to expose all the POD services directly to the user through multiple NodePorts.

Regarding your question about "what does Node's IP and port (provided by NodePort service) used for?"

- First NodePort is not responsible for providing any IP to your Nodes. each node already has its IPs. NodePort will just expose your POD/ Controller IP from a local port to Cluster Port which can be accessed by the user from outside.

Hopefully, this answers your question or you can ask the question again about which part you're not able to understand.